# I'm unable to figure out how to pass input from user

Tags: python, class

```py
class Temperature():
    def convertF(self,c):
        return c*1.8+32

    def convertC(self,f):
        return (f-32)*(5/9)

c=float(input())                
f=float(input())
n_temp=Temperature(c)
n_temp=Temperature(f)
print(n_temp.convertF)
print(n_temp.convertC)
```

I've creating a class `Temperature`, then I created 2 methods one for converting Celsius to Fahrenheit and another for converting the latter to former.
Now I want to take the values of Celsius and Fahrenheit from user but I'm getting the error :

> Temperature() takes no arguments.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with user-input. Do you need to use classes? If so, are you familiar with **constructors**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `Temperature(<value>)`, you need a constructor. Once you have a constructor, your other methods dont need parameters

```
class Temperature():
 def __init__(self, temp):
    self.temp = temp

 def convertF(self):
    return self.temp * 1.8 + 32

 def convertC(self):
    return (self.temp-32)*(5/9)

n_temp=Temperature(float(input()))
print(n_temp.convertC())  # you need to call the function
```

Or you can [use static methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) if you don't want to use a constructor (since the constructor itself doesn't know if the input is in Celcius, Farenheit, or Kelvin), but then you would need to remove the argument from the class initialization, and pass it to the functions

```
# call a static method
print(Temperature.convertC(0))  # 32
```

Answer (score 0):

*Temperature* (the class) doesn't take any arguments; each of its methods *does* take an argument.